# Example for monotone convergence

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm searching for an example of sequence of function in which if doesn't exist a Lebesgue integrable function g that increases the sequence, then the equality in the convergence theorem is not anymore maintained.

Thank you.

Comment: " if doesn't exist a Lebesgue integrable function g that increases the sequence" : what do you mean ? The monotone convergence theorem is true from the moment you have a positive increasing sequence; there is no more condition.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes, I want to prove what you wrote: if I haven't the positive increasing then the theorem in not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Take
$$f_n(t) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
       1 & \mbox{if } t \geq n \\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.$$

Then $$\int \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n = 0 \neq +\infty = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int f_n$$

You see here that the theorem is wrong if the sequence is decreasing.